# Graphql Apollo Optimistic UI pattern - handle actual result?

Tags: graphql, apollo, optimistic-ui

We are following the optimistic ui pattern (http://dev.apollodata.com/react/optimistic-ui.html) with the apollo graphql client.  Is there a way to handle the actual result from the server? For example, if the server did error on the mutation, we would like to notify the user. Is there a place to get the real result of the mutation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mutation returns a `Promise`. So you can handle the result from the server using `than` and `catch`.

If you are using the `update` functionality of the mutation definition you could use the `catch` to handle a server error. To get the error as object you could use `errorResponse = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mutationError))`

Comment: I don't think mutation responses are catchable anymore. The responses from a failed mutation will still comeback as success(200) but the data object from the resolved promise will have an error stored in data.error